# Getting PTK Test Running

Tags: c++

PTK is a 2d c++ framework for developing iphone apps on windows/mac. I followed the tutorial to set up a test app here: http://www.phelios.com/ptk/tuto1/

But I get the error
LNK1104: cannot open file 'dxguid.lib'

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010

My Project Properties/Linker/Input/Additional Dependancies is this:
libptkvc.lib
ksoundvcstatic.lib
winmm.lib
opengl32.lib
dsound.lib
dxguid.lib
ddraw.lib
d3dx.lib
wininet.lib
shell32.lib

edit: I can't comment on your answer, so I have to ask here, where would the directory containing dxguid.lib be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the library paths in project properties (Project Properties/Linker/General/Additional Library Directories). You probably miss the path that contains the dxguid.lib.